# Arduino & Rails integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arduino

I have developed a web aplication for storing sensor data.

Now I am starting the Arduino side development.

I have an arduino wiht network capabilities, of sensors and a relay. I want to send the information to my Rais app and activate the relay througth the web app.

Im thinking in connecting directly the arduino to the rails database (now im using SQLite, i have to  migrate to mySQL).

Whats the better way to do it?

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it would be beter to use the arduino [json-library](http://interactive-matter.eu/how-to/ajson-arduino-json-library/) to insert the data over the rails app. 
That way you are independent of any changes on the DB end and keep all the benefits of the MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using ajson, it makes it very 
simple to parse your arduino data.
http://interactive-matter.eu/blog/2010/08/14/ajson-handle-json-with-arduino/

Answer (score 0):

You could send sensor values through the internet via an Ethernet shield like the **ENC28J60** with the **EtherCard** library. Then you could make an RESTful API on your Rails app (e.g. with Grape), and from the Arduino shield, send the info to this API using the **EtherCard** library that I suggest.

With this, you have the sensor values stored on your Rails app, and then you could do whatever you want with the info. You could make the inverse process (send an request from your Rails app to the Arduino shield) using the **EtherCard** library too.

[Here you have](http://dreamingechoes.github.io/arduino/ruby/rails/physical-software-made-easy-with-arduino-and-ruby-on-rails/) an example to do the first part, the inverse one (from Rails to Arduino) is not more complex.